# Generate javascript code bootstrap tooltip issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrapping

I need to generate some results using ajax. The problem is by displaying this results I want to have an info icon with some information. For that purpose I am using the Bootstrap Tooltip. So fine so good, but when i generate the code dynamically using Javascript it does not show the tooltip like before, it is just like a title effect on a link.

The text inside is not fancy I have tried with the same text on the same page not using Javascript and it works fine.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advice

Comment: atlease show us js code, html code, how will we catch this issue without it ?

Comment: Only when u share your code that was happening we can help Vince

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Arkadiusz G. that's exactly what i needed !

Answer (score 0):

Add the data-toggle='tooltip' and title to the elements you want.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
```

And in a .js File or inline  tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
```

Needed it yesterday -> http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp